# C# Why need not to inherit object class while creating new class

Tags: c#

I have been asking myself this question for a long time now. Thought of posting it. Every class in .Net is inherited from object class, so why we need not to inherit object class while we create new class. Is there any thing that framework do by default in this case?

```
class Test
        {
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return base.ToString();
            }
        }


class MyClass : Object
        {
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return base.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Is there any difference in above two class declaration?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every `class` inherits `object` by default. You don't have to specify that because compiler will do it for you during compilation.

Example taken from specification:

> `class A {}`
>
> `class B: A {}`
>
> (...)
>
> Since `A` does not explicitly specify a direct base class, its direct base class is **implicitly** `object`.

There is no difference between your declarations.

> The object class type is the ultimate base class of all other types. **Every type in C# directly or indirectly derives from the object class type.**

*C# 5 Specification*

IT means, that if your class `C1` already inherits another class `C2` the `object` inheritance is not added by compiler, because it will be already available through `C2` class inheritance. **At the top of inheritance tree there is always `System.Object` class.**

Comment: Okay thanks.. One more question. When I inherit MyClass in Some other class then it's multi level inheritance or multilevel inheritance? I know this is silly question but just for my doubt.

Comment: I guess this knowledge can be found in any **basic c# book**.

Answer (score 2):

From [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx);

> **Because all classes in the .NET Framework are derived from Object**,
>   every method defined in the Object class is available in all objects
>   in the system.

So, you don't have *do* anything special. They are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the IL code the compiler ignore the Object.

```
    private class MyClass
    {

        public MyClass()
        {
            ldarg.0
            call     System.Object..ctor()
            ret
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            locals:
                V_0: string 

            ldarg.0
            call     string System.Object.ToString()
            stloc.0
            ldloc.0
            ret
        }

    } // class MyClass

    private class Test
    {

        public Test()
        {
            ldarg.0
            call     System.Object..ctor()
            ret
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            locals:
                V_0: string 

            ldarg.0
            call     string System.Object.ToString()
            stloc.0
            ldloc.0
            ret
        }

    } // class Test
```